# Migrating a custom user model onto an existing user model

Tags: python, django

So I have a website that was using the built in django user model with some extensions. For various reasons, I wanted to instead use a custom user model. I have it built and runs beautifully on my local machine.

Now, I have integrated it into the development version of my website, but I am having some problems. When I try to add a new field, the migrations won't work, because it tries to create a brand new initial table with the same names, which won't work. Using South for my migrations.

To combat that, I tried to rename all the tables, and then run the migrations, but that won't work because of foreign key issues. I tried to work around that, but ran into more problems when I tried to rename foreign keys.

If you would like more insight into the problem, please ask.

I feel as though there has gotta be an easier way to go about this. I would love any insight. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more information about your old and new model?

Comment: The two both have the same exact fields. The reason I am changing to use this custom user model instead is because I want it to be easier to make updates the user model in the future.